# Access user points in different drupal site

Tags: commerce, userpoints

We have 2 drupal sites, one as CMS and another one is SHOP.
In CMS site we are using userpoints module to award points to user on certain actions. 
Now my question is, How to use these points in SHOP site. Shop site is totally different form CMS site but hosted on sub-doamin.

In shop site we are using ubercart and Commerce-userpoints modules.

Comment: You need to create webservice for this to interact between both sites. https://drupal.org/node/113697

Comment: Ok. is there any alternative way where we can share tables? as we hv implemented SSO for this sites.

Comment: I think sharing table would be a difficult task here, https://drupal.org/project/userpoints provides Services integration to allow retrieving and updating points on your site using web services. So I would prefer to use web services here rest depends on your existing functionality and code :).